# Calculate total ON time from ON OFF timestamps

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing alternating ON & OFF events with its timestamp. How do i calculate total time between each ON & OFF?

```
Status        Timestamp
============================
ON       2019-01-01 07:00:00
OFF      2019-01-01 08:30:00
ON       2019-01-01 09:00:00
OFF      2019-01-01 10:00:00
ON       2019-01-01 10:30:00
OFF      2019-01-01 11:30:00
```

Comment: what columns indicates the order? And no, there is no default order.

Comment: (I'm guessing timestamp)

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 dt DATETIME NOT NULL,
 status VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2015-01-01 13:00:00','ON'),
(2,'2015-01-01 13:10:00','OFF'),
(3,'2015-01-01 13:20:00','ON'),
(4,'2015-01-01 13:30:00','OFF'),
(5,'2015-01-01 13:35:00','ON'),
(6,'2015-01-01 13:40:00','OFF'),
(7,'2015-01-01 13:50:00','ON'),
(8,'2015-01-01 15:00:00','OFF');

 SELECT x.*, 
 TIMEDIFF(MIN(y.dt),x.dt) AS TimeDiff 
 FROM my_table AS x 
 INNER JOIN my_table AS y ON y.dt >= x.dt 
 WHERE x.status = 'ON' AND y.status = 'OFF' 
 GROUP 
 BY x.id;
```

Refer DB FIDDLE For More:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00dc040da540f852f08b2f02750bc16d

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  `status` VARCHAR(3),
  `timestamp` VARCHAR(19)
);

INSERT INTO events
  (`status`, `timestamp`)
VALUES
  ('ON', '2019-01-01 07:00:00'),
  ('OFF', '2019-01-01 08:30:00'),
  ('ON', '2019-01-01 09:00:00'),
  ('OFF', '2019-01-01 10:00:00'),
  ('ON', '2019-01-01 10:30:00'),
  ('OFF', '2019-01-01 11:30:00');

SELECT 
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(
            SUM(TIMEDIFF(offtime, ontime))
          )), '%H:%i')
                 AS total FROM (
SELECT e.timestamp AS offtime, (SELECT  timestamp 
                               FROM events AS st WHERE st.timestamp < e.timestamp AND st.status = "ON"
                               ORDER BY st.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS ontime
FROM events AS e WHERE e.status='OFF') AS onoffs
```

Selects every OFF record, joins the most recent ON record to it, sums time ranges. With your data it gives the result: `total 03:30`

Doesn't account for open ranges. E.g. if the data series is started with OFF; or if it ends with ON, the time up to current moment would not be counted.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hr27GhACxGd7ZvFaa52xiK/0#